# Deploy GWT Project to Jetty // Error: Couldn't load from super devmode server at localhost:9876

Tags: java, maven, gwt, jetty

I'm trying to deploy a GWT Project on a Jetty Server and this Error message keeps poppin up:

```
   Couldn't load from super devmode server at localhost:9876
```

I am using Maven by the way, even though I'm not quite sure if the problem might be caused by it.

What could be the case here? Something I need to adjust? 
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a staleness check false positive in the gwt-maven-plugin that leads to a "build too few" case. Make sure you always do a clean build before deploying, or use `-Dgwt.compiler.force` to bypass the staleness check.